# set textview from antoher activity in android

Tags: java, android, null, textview

I'm having a problem with my app.

So, I'm trying to save some data into another activity, from mainactivity inputs. And I think I found the error but can't fix it.

I believe my app is searching for textview reference in wrong activity, in main. The problem is that I want to change another activity's textview. Is there anybody that could explain for me how to do that or give me some advice here?

```
public void saveEvent(View saveView){

    Saved save=new Saved();

    save.SaveNow(day,tvResultBefore.getText().toString(), tvResultAfter.getText().toString());
```

// Save class

```
public class Saved extends MainActivity {

TextView tvMonthResult;
TextView tvResultBef;
TextView tvResultAft;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_save);

    tvMonthResult=findViewById(R.id.tvMonthResult);
    tvResultBef=findViewById(R.id.tvResultBef);
    tvResultAft=findViewById(R.id.tvResultAft);

}

public void SaveNow(String day, String resBef, String resAft){

    tvMonthResult.setText(month);
    tvResultBef.setText(resBef);
    tvResultAft.setText(resAft);

}
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Can you share your whole involved code as well as the error?

Comment: You can use Intent Extras to pass data from one intent to another. It is the easiest way I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get values from **MainActivity** like this ::

> **MainActivity.class**

```
String data = editText.getText().toString();
Intent intent=new Intent(context,AnotherActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("DATA",data);
startActivity(intent);
```

Now, in AnotherActivty get value and set it to textview :

> **AnotherActivity.class**

```
if(getIntent!=null)
String data = getIntent().getStringExtra("DATA");
if(data!=null)
textView.setText(data);
```

it solved your problem.

Comment: Thank you very much! Worked like a sharm. Do you have any tips on how to make the set text to keep being saved into the new activity, like if i return and go back, it will still be there?